# If x and y are complex numbers then $x \perp y$ means $||x+iy||^2= ||x||^2 + ||y||^2$

Tags: complex-numbers, inner-products

I don't see how if $x$ and $y$ are elements of an inner product space of the complex numbers then saying $x \perp y$ is equivalent to saying $||x+y||^2= ||x||^2 +||y||^2$ and $||x+iy||^2= ||x||^2 +||y||^2$

I can see that $||x+y||^2= ||x||^2 +||y||^2$ is true. However how is it that $||x+iy||^2= ||x||^2 +||y||^2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that

$$\|x+\lambda y\|^2 = \langle x+\lambda y, x+\lambda y\rangle = \langle x, x\rangle + \lambda \langle y,x\rangle + \bar{\lambda}\langle x,y\rangle + \lambda\bar{\lambda} \langle y,y\rangle.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: what is $\bar{\lambda}$?

Comment: The complex conjugate. You may know it instead as $\lambda^*$ which is the same thing expressed differently.

Comment: Regarding the definition of the inner product. Denote = $a_x+ib_x$ and y = $a_y+ib_y$ the inner product is defined as  $<x,y> = a_x a_y+b_x b_y$ right?

Comment: @compleyboi You seem to be talking about an inner product of two complex numbers, considered as $2$-dimensional **real** vectors like $(a_x,b_x)$. But the question is about inner products of vectors in **complex** inner product spaces.